# AWS key stopped working randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

My AWS access key just decided to stop working today. No clue as to why. I've never had something like this happen before. The only thing I can think of is that I added an IAM use last week for an IT person to access RDS. Other than that - totally random. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

In the AWS console go to IAM and check the access keys for the user associated with the key that has stopped. It sounds like it was made inactive by mistake or by someone else in your account. Either that or the policies have been revoked or changed.

You can create a new key or make active the previous key. CLI command aws iam get-access-key-last-used to find out the latest it was active. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

I've also never experienced a key not working without cause.

As suggested Cloud Trail is the way to find out who did what specifically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you mention you have access to the IAM console, you can try
   using the [IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to check if you still have
   access.
2. This will also help you debug what went wrong.
3. To answer your question directly, no, I've not faced any such issue
   where I lost access, unless someone fiddled with the IAM Console.
4. If you've enabled [AWS Cloud Trial](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/), you should be able to figure
   out what changed and by whom.